# Give cordinates to map in Sencha 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I cant figure out how to feed the Sencha 2 map with coordinates, tried something like this (somewhere on the Internets I saw someone using that properties, but its not defined in the config list in the map API).
I cant find any config property or method which makes sense to use, what do I overlook?

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Map

```
this.getLoginview().push({
    xtype: 'map',
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    //useCurrentLocation: true
});
```

Comment: What do you mean 'feed with coordinates' ? Do you want to pan to a special area or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(60.358115,5.169067);
var map = new Ext.Map({
      mapOptions: {
          center: position
      },

      }
});

loginView.push(map);
```